# Can't set property on javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Full gist: https://gist.github.com/jonny2779/1e59c3a97b910b09240c

Self is a js model with all the methods inside it.

```
Moodboard.prototype = {
```

The code:

```
      var self = this;
      self.isArchived = true;
      self.foo = true;
      console.log('is archived property', self.isArchived);
      console.log('self object', self);
      return self.save();
```

The results of this code: (Note that self.foo is set)

[[image: console screenshot showing <code>true</code> standalone <code>isArchived</code> property but <code>false</code> property inside object][1]]

Why is self.isArchived not being set when self.foo is being set?

Also, why is it set when i do object.property and not when I log just the object?

**TLDR;**

Console.log() is async. In my screenshot it shows the property set to what I wanted. When you expand a console.log(); it seems to 're-fire' the event and can get different values. This is because the save() method is also async and manipulates the original object.

Comment: `.isArchived` is showing as false. so it must be set. is there more code we should see?

Comment: `isArchived` could be a protected property. More about properties [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: note that `isArchived` shows as `true` in the single line representation of the object in your screenshot...

Comment: The line after the _Moodboard_ shows `isArchived:true`

Comment: Please see edits. Uploaded full gist

Comment: your save(); is doing what?
//I couldn't reproduce this issue

Comment: the save has been uploaded in the gist. I think it might be where it says var self = this; in the save method.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak wow. You are right. Totally missed that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue arises from console.log being asynchronous: when you log the self object, only a reference is logged, which gets evaluated when you click on it.

**Notice this in your [screenshot](http://puu.sh/hDuFn/2bba2c1907.png)**: in the first line of the console message (unopened state), `isArchived` is `true` as expected. Only when you open it manually to inspect further is it listed as `false`. Probably something else is modifying it between logging and manual opening.

(I bet you would not be seeing this behaviour if you logged self.isArchived directly, because as a primitive value that would be printed immediately.)

Comment: Maybe you re changing isArchived in your save() function?

Comment: So I commented out the save method and it is being set properly. It must be something in there. I uploaded a full gist. You should be able to see it now.